# How to hide a div with a specific class if it appears at the end of a parent?

Tags: html, css

So the question is not just merely asking about using :last-child. Rather, it is asking how to target a div with css with a specific class if it comes at the end of the parent.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/012cq8nu/3/

I want no white dividers below the last `content` div.

Comment: You mean if the last class is `child`, you want to hide all `child` within `parent`?

Comment: share your needed output

Comment: Yes, but only if they are appearing at the end. I do not want any `child` to the end.

However, if a `child` is appearing above `content` that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to hide all `child` after `content`? If yes, then this will do the trick:

```
.content ~ .child {
    display: none;
}
```

`~` selects all subsequent elements.

Comment: It may work specifically in that case, but not in the case if there's a `child` between the `content`.

Example attached below:
https://jsfiddle.net/012cq8nu/2/

Comment: Yeah sure, you never mentioned there would be multiple `content` elements... What would be the expected output then? To show the `child` between the two `content`?

Comment: It's simple. Have a look at this fiddle, will include it in the question as well.
https://jsfiddle.net/012cq8nu/3/

I want no white dividers below the last `content` div.

Comment: Now obviously I can just say
    .content:nth-of-type(2) ~ .child {
        display: none;
    }
But that is not a solution I'm looking for, since again, there can be many different `content` divs.

Comment: I see what you mean. Sadly that's not possible with just CSS, as CSS has no "Previous Selector", only "Next Selector" (`~` and `+`). So you will need Javascript. If you are interested in a possible JS solution, you can check this Fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/012cq8nu/5/

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot. Yeah, was thinking that it might not be possible.